# is it possible to upgrade marklogic cluster in place without uninstalling each instance of MarkLogic Server

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-dhf

for a production enviromont running older version instance of MarkLogic Serve is it possible to upgrading it with out uninstalling marklogic.

I have tried to search all of the internet to check if this is possible and did not find anything helpful.

my boss is saying "If you are in a real world environment, you cannot uninstall the servers"

any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/rolling-upgrades.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your boss means by that, but I am pretty sure that for most software, this is exactly what happens during an upgrade: the new code is installed, and the old one is removed.  Even if this might be hidden to some extend, behind some automatic upgrade process.

Basically, for a MarkLogic instance, it means uninstalling the software and installing the new version.  Of course, all data and configuration is kept during the uninstallation.

The downtime is quite short (typically in minutes for each host.)  If this is not acceptable for your business, look for "[rolling upgrades](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/rolling-upgrades.html)" in the manual.

Of course, test the upgrade process in lower environments.  Test your application on the new version as well.

It is not unusual for clients to seek help of their preferred Professional Services consultant to help them during upgrades, given the sensitive nature of the process.